# Firebase Cloud Storage security rules: what do "/b/" and "/o" mean in bucket match statement?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

This question is regarding Firebase Cloud Storage security rules, documented at https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security and related pages.

The statement to match a generic bucket is `match /b/{bucket}/o`: the documents explain that `{bucket}` is a wildcard (akin to `*`) to match any bucket name, but to me it seems that the meaning of the leading `/b/` and trailing `/o` are left unexplained, can anyone help me understand the meaning of those path segments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/b` signals the next component of the URI is the relevant bucket: `/b/{bucket}`.

The `/o` signals the next component of the URI is the name (or path) of the relevant object in that bucket: `/o/path/to/object.png`

**Note**: Storage Buckets don't have a concept of folders, an object's name can include slashes, but to the server, the slash is just part of the file name and has no special meaning.

So a rule that names `/b/{bucket}/o/publicUserFiles/{request.auth.uid}/profile.png` would define a rule for the `profile.png` file, stored in a "folder" named with the relevant user's UID, under another "folder" called `publicUserFiles`, in the relevant bucket.

Instead of putting `/b/{bucket}/o` at the front of every rule, you can lift it out to the top of the file.

i.e.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o/images/{imageId} {
    allow write: // some rule here;
  }
  match /b/{bucket}/o/profileImages/{imageId} {
    allow write: // some rule here;
  }
}
```

becomes

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /images/{imageId} {
      allow write: // some rule here;
    }

    match /profileImages/{imageId} {
      allow write: // some rule here;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Very clearly explained, thank you. Now though I don't understand the need for those segments: according to https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/buckets a bucket name cannot contain a `/`, so why wasn't a simpler URI pattern such as `{bucket}/path/to/object` chosen, which would only require to split the string at the first `/` to find the bucket's and the object's names?

Comment: @kynikos While I agree that it could be simplified now, it made sense for the time the APIs were designed because it made parsing the information unambiguous. Now that efficiency of cloud computing is prioritised, the Storage Rules URLs follow the same format as the API to make parsing them as computationally cheap as possible.